# ASP.NET MVC Area works on local server, not on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP.NET MVC Area for admin, this is the code in AdminAreaRegistration.cs

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "myadmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Never a problem locally when testing in Visual Studio, area contents load successfully.

Now I have published the website to Azure, and the admin area doesn't load on the production server, I get this error.

> The controller for path '/myadmin/' was not found or does not implement IController.

The Area code is within my main project, which I verified to be present on Azure as .dll, so I don't think Azure is missing a file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it was really trivial, I was stupid enough to type wrong path in my browser. :-/

The `/myadmin/` path never worked locally either. I was using `/myadmin/home` the whole time, but I didn't notice because it was bookmarked. `/myadmin/home` loads on Azure too without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` to Global.asax ?

And Area name have to be override with the current name, like on example:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "myadmin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "myadmin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips! It turned out that I was just using the wrong path in my browser - doh.